# Show latest ID and company ID based on job ID

Tags: mysql

Table: **service**

```
id companyid jobid
 1         1     1
 2         1     2
 3         1     2
 4         2     3
 5         3     4
 6         3     1
 7         4     2
 8         5     2
```

I type the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM service
WHERE jobID = 2
ORDER BY companyID desc, ID desc
```

And I get the below output:

```
id companyid jobid
 8         5     2
 7         4     2
 3         1     2 
 2         1     2
```

But I want my expected output is below:

```
id companyid jobid
 8         5     2
 7         4     2
 3         1     2
```

How do I modify the query in order to get my expected output?

Comment: Do you want the latest 3 rows based on that order? If so you just need to add `LIMIT 3 ` after the order by clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just apply the `max` function along with a `group by` clause:

```
select max(id) id, companyid, jobid
from service
where jobid = 2
group by companyid, jobid
order by id desc
```

Given your sample data the result would be:

```
id  companyid   jobid
8   5           2
7   4           2
3   1           2
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select * from service s1
join (select max(id) as id 
      from service 
       group by jobid, companyid) s2 on s1.id = s2.id
where s1.jobid = 2--can comment to select all latest jobs
```